# is there a way to call a function in a model to set a value? ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to have a value in a model changed depending on a function that I have already made is there a way to do this?

```
public bool TempBool = !!!!!!!where i function needs be called!!!!!!;
        [Compare(nameof(TempBool), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RegisterModelConsentErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SharedResource))]
        [Display(Name = "RegisterModelConsentDisplayName", ResourceType = typeof(SharedResource))]
        public bool Consent { get; set; }
```

the function i want to call is below.

```
public bool CheckGdpr()
    {
        string str = _configuration["privacy:GDPR"];
        string checkbol = "True";
        if (checkbol == str)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

`public class RegisterModel
{                                                                                                                              public bool DisableChangePassword { get; set; }

```
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public RegisterModel(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
    public bool TempBool => Convert.ToBoolean(_configuration["privacy:GDPR"]);
    [Compare(nameof(TempBool), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RegisterModelConsentErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SharedResource))]
    [Display(Name = "RegisterModelConsentDisplayName", ResourceType = typeof(SharedResource))]
    public bool Consent { get; set; }
}`
```

but having a public Registermodel throw way to may errors for my project is there another way to do this will out naming it the same as the class?

Comment: What have you tried? Seems like `public bool TempBool = CheckGdpr();` should do the job, if the function is in the same class.

Comment: You mean public bool TempBool { get; set; } = CheckGdpr(); ?

Comment: use the convenient syntax of readonly property here: `public bool TempBool { get; set; } => CheckGdpr();` - If you want your property to have getter & setter, looks like just acces your `_configuration` directly like this `public bool TempBool { get => _configuration["privacy:GDPR"] == "True"; set => _configuration["privacy:GDPR"] = value.ToString(); }`

Comment: @KingKing when i used the Configuration to get my global i get an error that reads: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0103 The name 'Configuration' does not exist in the current context DAL C:\Users\Isaac\source\repos\elearn2-final_sapce_fixes\Elearn\DAL\Models\Account.cs 124 Active

Comment: is there a using configuration that I need to include?

Comment: I thought you already had an instance of `IConfiguration` named `_configuration`. So here you use another name of `Confiugration` somewhere else and it's not defined. The `IConfiguration` can be injected in your service/controller constructor. In this case looks like you use it in your view model class, so that means the view model will need to be manually initialized and provided with an instance of `IConfiguration` from the outside context (e.g: called in some Controller). You can see how `Configuration` is obtained in the `Startup` class.

Comment: @KingKing  i have "using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;" and i am able to get my global variable now but It seems to be giving me problems with the naming convention. this is what i have now. please check the question again to see my added code.

Comment: not sure what it is, it could be a name conflict, I'm still not even sure what you have on your side (as well as about the issue you have now). If it is a name conflict issue, you can try looking around (right in the file you have the error) to see if there are any special names you have for your class, namespace, ... Special names here usually match with what you are trying to use from the framework.

Comment: what I mean by name conflict is that there in the rest of my project when i am trying reference the register model then it gives me an error that:                                   
   Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'configuration' of 'RegisterModel.RegisterModel(IConfiguration)' Elearn C:\Users\Isaacr\source\repos\elearn2-final_sapce_fixes\Elearn\Elearn\Controllers\AccountController.cs 113 Active

Answer (score 1):

You can use like that

```
public bool TempBool //= !!!!!!!where i function needs be called!!!!!!;
{
    get
    {
        return CheckGdpr();
    }
    set{}   
}
[Compare(nameof(TempBool), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RegisterModelConsentErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SharedResource))]
[Display(Name = "RegisterModelConsentDisplayName", ResourceType = typeof(SharedResource))]
public bool Consent { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'configuration' of 'RegisterModel.RegisterModel(IConfiguration)' Elearn C:\Users\Isaacr\source\repos\elearn2-final_sapce_fixes\Elearn\Elearn\Controllers\AccountController.cs 113 Active

For this error,that is because you create a new instance of the RegisterModel but you do not pass the IConfiguration to it in your AccountController.

```
public class AccountController: Controller
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public AccountController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public voidIndex()
    {
        var data = new RegisterModel(_configuration);
    }
}
```